# What's wrong in regex format for filenames in <regex> VS10?

Tags: c++, regex, visual-studio

I'm trying to parse filenames paths by  in Visual Studio 2010.
But program crashes with 
`Microsoft C++ exception: std::tr1::regex_error at memory location 0x001ef120..` 
on 
`regex myRegEx("^([a-zA-Z]\\:)(\\\\[^\\\\/:*?<>\"|]*(?<![ ]))*(\\.[a-zA-Z]\\{2,6\\})$");`

Regular expression is `^([a-zA-Z]\:)(\\[^\\/:*?<>"|]*(?<![ ]))*(\.[a-zA-Z]{2,6})$`

What's wrong with regex format?

Comment: try catching the exception and printing `.what()`.

Comment: @ybungalobill regular expression error

Answer (score 0):

You can perhaps narrow things down by slicing it into chunks.  Evaluate the atoms separately, and see where the error turns up:

```
"^([a-zA-Z]\\:).*$"
"^([a-zA-Z]\\:)(\\\\[^\\\\/:*?<>\"|]*(?<![ ]))*[.]*$"
"^([a-zA-Z]\\:)(\\\\[^\\\\/:*?<>\"|]*(?<![ ]))*(\\.[a-zA-Z]+)$"
"^([a-zA-Z]\\:)(\\\\[^\\\\/:*?<>\"|]*(?<![ ]))*(\\.[a-zA-Z]\\{2,6\\})$"
```

One possible gotcha is the range, "\{2,6\}".  If you really want "two to six letters", then you don't want backslashes in the middle of the range.  The real answer depends on your parser.

Also, if there's confusion as to what's being escaped with backslashes, remember that you can often escape special characters by putting them into a range.  For example, `\\` may be equivalent to `[\]`, and `\.` is certainly equivalent to `[.]`.

Comment: Okay, then start breaking down the rest of the regex into simpler-but-less-specific pieces.  `"^([a-zA-Z]\\:)(...*(?<![ ]))*[.]*$"` then `"^([a-zA-Z]\\:)(..[^/:*?<>|]*(?<![ ]))*[.]*$"` then `"^([a-zA-Z]\\:)(..[^/:*?<>\"|]*(?<![ ]))*[.]*$"` etc.  Add the elements of the original regex piece by piece until you see what breaks.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I don't know well c++ regex syntax but, it seems to me that `\\[` means escape the `[` character.

I guess you should code just as `[` if you want a negated character class `[^\\/:*?<>"|]`

```
^([a-zA-Z]\:)([^\\/:*?<>"|]*(?<![ ]))*(\.[a-zA-Z]{2,6})$
```

Answer (score 0):

`tr1::regex` doesn't support lookbehind, so it's choking on `"(?<![ ])"`.

Unfortunately, I'm not enough of a regex user to give you guidance on what you might use instead.